# Bootstrap carousel prev/next buttons not responding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So here is another instance of the million questions asking why Bootstrap's carousel isn't working.  From what I can tell though, no one else has the same problem as me.  You probably don't believe me, and maybe I don't fully believe myself either.  Anyways, here goes.

So my code is a literal copy and paste from [Bootstrap's carousel example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/), with some minor changes here and there.  Feel free to copy paste into your own html file and view it.  I've included Bootstrap's css and javascript, I've included jquery, and I've initialized my carousel.  What specifically isn't working is the left and right buttons.  Their expected behavior is to cycle through the images in each item div, but what actually happens is nothing.  The carousel didn't work when copied from the example's page source, and it didn't work after I made my changes.

As a note, I did see the warning about viewing the page via a file:// URL, and the code doesn't work when hosted to an S3 bucket either.

First one to point out why I'm dumb gets free points!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    });
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="http://www.mountainprofessor.com/images/Mountain-Ranges-Colorado-2.jpg" alt="First slide" style="width:100%;height:500px;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/50/6943013-mountain-lake.jpg" alt="Second slide" style="width:100%;height:500px">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Example text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the solution!  I just needed to load JQuery before before loading Bootstrap's Javascript.  As to why this ordering is necessary, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browsers console

Do you See

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

It looks like its not loading Jquery 1st

The order of the scripts should be like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working!  So if I understand this correctly, the error was simply that I was loading bootstrap before jquery?  Is this something that everyone knows to avoid, or is this just an eccentric bug in my specific case?

Comment: @Ryan That's correct, i got confused myself cause i thought it was the wrong version but second time i checked i realized the issue. Any Framework or custom scripts that require Jquery to work, e.g like boostrap uses inbuilt functions like ( $('#myCarousel').carousel();)  needs to load Jquery js  first and then the framework